# How to wisely associate Survey objects with existing Person objects avoiding redundancy in Entity Framework in ASP .NET MVC 5 Web Application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a `class Person` i would like to associate object of `class Survey` with it. Of course `Survey` consists of `Question` objects and `Question` consists of `Answer` objects.

The problem is that if for example I have 10000 `Person`s(tops) in database and every one of them will fullfil **exacly the same** survey I might end up with 9999 redundant `Question` or `Survey` objects instead of just remembering the answers.

Accoridng to this tutorial: http://www.techiesweb.net/radio-button-list-in-asp-net-mvc/

I have done something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    public class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Surveys")]
        public virtual ICollection<Survey> Surveys { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and Survey part:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    public class Question {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string QuestionText { set; get; }
        public virtual  ICollection<Answer> Answers { set; get; }
        public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; }
        public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }


    }
    public class Answer {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string AnswerText { set; get; }
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    }
    public class Survey {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { set; get; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    }
}
```

but I feel this might end up with terrible amount of unecessary data.

How to solve this to avoid big amount of code while initializing those Surveys for every user and waste of memory.

**EDIT:** Current version of code:

### Models/Survey.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    public class Question {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string QuestionText { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { set; get; }
        public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
        public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; } //this field is SET after clicking SAVE SURVEY button
        /*    public Question() {
                Answers = new List<Answer>();
            }*/
    }
    public class Answer {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string AnswerText { set; get; } 
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }
    public class Survey {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { set; get; }

        /*  public Survey() {
              Questions = new List<Question>();
          }*/
    }
}
```

### Models/Person.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    public class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Cell Number")]
        public string CellNumber { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Secondary Number")]
        public string SecondaryPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Pesel")]
        public string Pesel { get; set; }


        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [DisplayName("Notes")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
        public int? StatusId { get; set; }
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Agreed to process personal data processing")]
        public bool PersonalDataProcessing { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    }
}
```

### View which shows all the Surveys _Survey1.cshtml (Partial View of Details.html):

```
@using WebApplication2.Models
@model   System.Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>

<hr />
<h1>Surveys</h1>
<input type="button" id="Coll" value="Collapse" onclick="javascript:CollapseDiv()" />
@*<p>
        Number of Surveys: @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Item2.Count)
    </p>*@

@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var survey in Model.Item2) {
    using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <h2>Survey @(i)</h2>
        <p />
        @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions)
        <button class='mybutton' type='button'  onclick="javascript:SubmitClick(@Model.Item1.Id, @survey.Id.);" >Click Me</button>
    }
    i++;
    <hr style="background-color:rgb(126, 126, 126);height: 5px" />
}
<hr />
```

### EditorTemplates/Question.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Question
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    <h3> @Model.QuestionText </h3>
    @foreach (var a in Model.Answers) {
        <p>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(b => b.SelectedAnswer, a.Id)  @a.AnswerText
        </p>
    }
</div>
```

And the _Survey.cshtml view looks like:

[image]

When I click the Save Survey button I invoke method from `Controllers/PersonController.cs`:

```
   public void SubmitSurvey(int personId, int surveyId) {
            //getting last selected answers from database and adding them to person
            //----PSEUDO CODE---- just to demonstrate
            Person person = db.findById(personId);
            List<Question> list = dbFindById(surveyId).Questions;
            person.Answers.Add(list);
            //---PSEUDO CODE----
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UPDATING DATABASE");

        }
```

which suppose to add selected answers to the Person.

Selected answers before clicking Save Survey will be remembered on field `public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; } //this field is SET after clicking SAVE button` in `class Question`, this is stated in `EditorTemplates.Question.cshtml`.

**Question**: My concern is: if 2 users(on different PCs) will open 2 people(different) and try to submit the same surveys at the same time (There are only 2 surveys in database and there is only one field SelectedAnswer in every Question) will their request cross each other on server side?

For instance by same results of the survey will be saved for both people? Or their answers will mix?

Comment: this needs a bit of refactoring, but it would definitely be easier to discuss in a chat than to describe the refactor here.... let's use http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59896/discuss-entity-framework-many-to-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on the conversation in chat, the refactoring is as follows:

Remove the references between `Person` and `Survey`

Add `ICollection<Person> People` to `Answer`, Add `ICollection<Answer> Answers` to `Person`

use [Entity Framework Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ591617.aspx) to create a many to many relationship between `Person` and `Answer` as follows:

`modelbuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(p => p.Answers).WithMany(a => a.People)`

Comment: Hello, I don't know when you'll be back on stacoverflow. Because you know the concept very well I would like to kindly ask you to look at the EDTI in original post. Because of the way the selected answers are remembered I am afraid that current model will not work for multiple users. Thank you for any shared thoughts. I tought about making `HashSet<ApplicationUser, List<Answer>' in Question but in don't know enough about Razor views.

Comment: the `SelectedAnswer` field on the question is actually not necessary.  what should happen is, when an answer is submitted, you add the `Person` to the `Answer` then `SaveChanges()`.  Now, if you look up an answer and see a collection of 10 people, you know 10 people selected that answer. Note that you may need extra logic to make sure that people can't be on more than one answer for each question, but that's easily handled elsewhere.

Comment: Selecting only one answer works(EditorTemplate) the problem is checking which one are selected without the `SelectedAnswer` field. I'll be back to this topic later(it is nearly 2am here). Thank you for you help.